# Count number of entries per day for particular user in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the number of orders received for a specified user per day. It's a simple table with id (int), user (int), day (Y-M-D H:I:S). Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such a SQL statement with grouping

```
select user, date(day) as day, 
       count(id) as number_of_orders
  from tab
 group by user, date(day)
```

*where `date()` function extracts `date` portion from a `datetime` expression*